# Как сделать перевод вещественных чисел из 2 в 8 систему счисления на си?

Tags: c, функции, циклы, условия, системы-счисления

Нужно сделать перевод числа из 2 системы счисления в 8, в том числе вещественные (типо 011.1)
Но вот как это сделать, я не особо понимаю, пока есть только с целыми числами:

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    char c;
    int result = 0;
    printf("Введите число в 2 системе счисления: ");
    while (scanf("%c", &c))
    {
        if ((c < '0') || (c > '1')) break;
        result <<= 1;
        result += c - '0';
    }
    printf("Ваше число в 8 системе счисления %o\n", result);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Можно попробовать спрашивать сначала целую часть, а потом дробную, но как их соединить, и что делать если пользователь например захочет ввести целое число без дробной части?

Comment: Изюминка задачи в том что вам не нужно работать с числами. Достаточно работать с группами символов.

Comment: Вещественное число состоит из двух целых чисел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно узнать длину числа, точнее каждого символа, чтобы мы могли каждый разряд перевести в десятичную систему.

```
const int value = 1010111;
    
int length = 0;
int tempValue = value;
while (tempValue)
{
    tempValue /= 10;
    length++;
}
```

Потом перевести в десятичную систему:

```
tempValue = 0;
for (int i = length; i > 0; i--)
    tempValue += (bool)((1 << (i - 1)) & value) * pow(2, i - 1);
```

Ну а дальше последовательное деление на 8. Перевернуть массив и будет двоичное число в восьмеричном виде.

Comment: Несколько нелепо переводить в десятичную, когда тройки двоичных разрядов уже соответствуют восьмеричным разрядам